# Accessing and using an image in an Unity Android Plugin

Tags: java, c#, android, plugins, unity-game-engine

Righty... I have never written anything in C# or Java before, so I am likely completely wrong in all of this and probably is a simple answer but here goes...

I have a ultra simple Unity app that simply fires an android plugin. The plugin needs to accept a text string and an image which it will do a form of share.

C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class RunStuff : MonoBehaviour {
    AndroidJavaClass androidClass;
    AndroidJavaObject androidActivity;

    void Start () {
        Debug.Log ("----- UNTIY SCRIPT INIT ----- ");

        var pathToImage = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/meagain.jpg";
        Debug.Log (pathToImage);

        AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread ();
        androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.something.something.Plugin");
        androidActivity = androidClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mContext");
        androidActivity.Call("Plugin", pathToImage , "SOME TEST STRING");

        Debug.Log ("----- UNTIY SCRIPT END ----- ");
    }
}
```

Java

```
package com.something.something;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class Plugin extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    public static Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        mContext = this;
    }

    public void Plugin(String imagePath, String message) {
        Log.d("TAG", imagePath);
        Log.d("TAG", message);

        // HERE I NEED TO BE ABLE TO USE THE IMAGE
    }
}
```

All this works correctly, as in I receive the imagePath and message within the java class... However I simply cannot grab the image from the imagepath.

The image is within the Unity project under StreamingAssets/meagain.jpg. If I extract the generated apk I can see the file, but all my attempts have failed!

Anybody got any ideas?!!

Comment: instead of streamingAssets you could use Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + imageName.

Comment: @ApolloSoftware Trying that the path appears to be wrong... and still fails... /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.something.something/files/meagain.jpg

Comment: where is the exact location of the jpg when you extract the file? Where in the path is it?

Comment: @ApolloSoftware APK/assets/meagain.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
    Texture2D myTex;
string url = "file://"+Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + textureName;    
WWW www = new WWW(url );
    myTex = www.texture;
```

Only way I know how to load stuff from streamignAssets.

Comment: That returns an error for me: 
Exception: JNI: Unknown signature for type 'UnityEngine.Texture2D' (obj =  (UnityEngine.Texture2D)) instance

Comment: maybe try it with just a texture type and not a texture2d.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android java you'd use something like

```
 InputStream in = mContext.getAssets().open("meagain.jpg");
```

or maybe

```
 InputStream in = Plugin.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("meagain.jpg");
```

Neither are tested, but worth a shot!

Also did some research:

```
/* from your subroutine */
Bitmap newBitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(mContext, imagePath);

/* new function to get Bitmap From Asset */
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String imagePath) {
  AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

  InputStream istr;
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  try {
    istr = assetManager.open(imagePath);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
  }

  return bitmap;
}
```

Also don't forget the imports for Bitmap, AssetManager, InputStream, BitmapFactory, and IOException.

Comment: Shall give those a try and see what happens!